# cx_Oracle. Как на этапе отладки посмотреть запрос, сгенерированный процедурой cursor.execute()?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Всем привет.
Нужна помощь "белковых" специалистов, т.к. бездушные "чаты" уже второй день бестолку гоняют меня по кругу своих ошибочных версий :D

Допустим, у меня есть следующий код:

```
    import cx_Oracle

    # SQL-запрос
    query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = :name AND age = :age"
    
    # параметры для запроса
    params = {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 30}
    
    cursor.execute(f"""{query}""", params)
```

Есть ли возможность увидеть (в логе или print`ом), какой селект получился после подставления в него моих параметров? То есть, убедиться, что итоговый запрос получился корректным:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'John Doe' AND age = 30
```

а не с какими-то ошибками синтаксиса, вроде:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ''John Doe'' AND age = 30
```